# Dynamic distribution groups: Which DDGs is user part of?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server-2010

I know how to get all the members of a dynamic distribution group: I can take the distribution group, get the AD filters from `msExchDynamicDLFilter` and `msExchQueryFilter` properties and query the AD for the users who match that filter.

Now, how do I go the other way? E.g. show which dynamic distribution groups a user is part of? Is there any better way than taking all the hundreds of dynamic distribution groups from AD, resolving each of them, one after the other, and looking whether the user is in the resolved list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not.  DDGs where created for Exchange.  So upon message submission, the DDGs are resolved.

That being said, you can only retrieve all DDGs, do the queries and check to see which one yield the desired user.